# Exact form of distance preserving map $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be distance preserving, i.e., $|T(a)-T(b)|=|a-b|$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb R^2.$ From here can we say the exact form of $T$?

If $T(x)=Ax+b,$   where $A^TA=I$ and $x,b\in \mathbb R^2$ and $b$ is fixed, then $T$ is distance preserving.

But my question is that 'Can we say that the above mentioned mappings are only distance preserving map?'

Comment: Reduce to the case that $T(0) = 0$ by replacing $T$ with $S(x) = T(x) - T(0)$.

Comment: Closely related: [Classification of Euclidean plane isometries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332056/classification-of-euclidean-plane-isometries)